# How to create a collage in JES

Tags: python, jython, jes

I have a project to create a collage with 6 copies of an image with some flipped, some with color changes, etc. I am completely new to all of this, and have barely any idea what I'm doing. I wrote out my code, but when I test it in JES and command explore(newpicture), a white box pops up titled 'None'. I've tried to mess with it, but am stuck. I have all my defs prior to this for flipping, changing color percents, etc. I imagine my issue is that I'm testing incorrectly or it is with my offset or collage code below. 
For testing I am inputting:

```
    verticalPicture = flipVertically(myPict)
    redPicture = matchRedToGreen(myPict)
    negativePicture = negative(myPict)
    bluePicture = clearBlue(myPict)
    clockwisePicture = rotateC90(myPict)
    newpicture = makeCollage(myPict)
    explore(newpicture)

def offsetPicture(littlePicture, bigPicture, xOffset, yOffset):
  for aPixel in getPixels(myPict):
  littleX = getX(aPixel)
  littleY = getY(aPixel)
  bigX = littleX + xOffset
  bigY = littleY + yOffset
  bigPicturePixel = getPixel (bigPicture, bigX, 375)
  setColor(bigPicturePixel, getColor (aPixel))

def makeCollage(myPict):
 newWidth = 3*getWidth(myPict)
 newHeight = 2*getHeight(myPict)
 bigPicture = makeEmptyPicture(newWidth, newHeight)
 offsetPicture(littlePicture, bigPicture, 0, 0)
 offsetPicture(clockwisePicture, bigPicture, getWidth(myPict), 0)
 offsetPicture(redPicture, bigPicture, 0, getHeight(myPict))
 offsetPicture(bluePicture, bigPicture, 2*getWidth(myPict), 0)
 offsetPicture(verticalPicture, bigPicture, getWidth(myPict), getHeight(myPict))
 offsetPicture(negativePicture, bigPicture, 2*getWidth(myPict), 2*getHeight(myPict))
return (bigPicture)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few indentation errors in your code. I don't know if this is a result of copying and pasting your code into Stack Overflow.

The errors found:

- The `return` statement of `makeCollage()` needs to be indented one more space.
- The statements after the for loop in `offsetPicture()` need to be indented.

Also the following lines of code you had at the top. These lines should go after you have defined your functions.

```
verticalPicture = flipVertically(myPict)
redPicture = matchRedToGreen(myPict)
negativePicture = negative(myPict)
bluePicture = clearBlue(myPict)
clockwisePicture = rotateC90(myPict)
newpicture = makeCollage(myPict)
explore(newpicture)
```